# How do I create a stack navigator with visible layers in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to recreate this style of stack navigator in react native.
[image]

Here is a video of it working: https://youtu.be/l2sMaurPY5E

The way it works is, when you tap on something, the current screen shrinks slightly and the new screen appears on top of it. Then you see a visible stack at the top of the screen, showing the layers.

Is this possible with React Native, or more specifically, React Navigation? I don't even know what it's called to search for it.

Comment: Thx for the edit @Kartikey. It wouldn't let me add the photo because of low rep.

Comment: This looks like a [Modal](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal). This kind of an effect can be achieved using a custom library like [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in React Naviagtion by simply settings `presentation` to `modal` to your desired screen (via `options` property , or as `screenOptions` to the entire stack if that's what you want). To make it work in Android, you might have to pass a few additional props.

In simple terms, you can define your navigator like below,

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator
    //define below properties to enable the modal presentation
    screenOptions={{ 
      presentation: 'modal',
      headerMode: 'none',
      cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forModalPresentationIOS,
      gestureEnabled: true,
      cardOverlayEnabled: true,
    }}
  >
    <Stack.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
    <Stack.Screen name="Modal" component={Modal} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

**Take a look at this [Live Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/react-navigation-modal-screen) to see it in action.**

[image]